# Android Studio Smallest Width 360dp

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, layout, screen-density

first of all i already read the documentacion of Android but definitely there is something that im not understanding.

My device has a smalles width configuration of 360, so all the UI it sees different. On my adventure to fix this, i read about this problem and created a layout with the annotation of smallest width 360 but the problem is i dont have a emulator in Android Studio that shows me this so i cant design the new layout for my device properly.

How can i see in Android Studio how this layout its gona see it in my device?

Thanks to all!

Comment: I have something on my phone in Settings > Display > Display size which seems to have the effect you want (on Pixel 2). However I don't know if it actually changes the screen width in dp.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I know how to do this but its not what i looking for. You can change the smallest width dp config in you phone, Settings > Developer > System > Developer options. And there is an option that allow you to change that setting. But what i need is see the layout design in Android Studio so i can modify to a good UI for my devices and all devices with my settings. Because i can change my settings but i cant ask to all people do it for use my app